# Simulating For inside For in SQL

Tags: sql, pentaho, etl, kettle, vertica

I'm using HP Vertica 7 as data warehouse DB.

I need to update two tables at the same time.

```
foreach (row r in table_1)
{
  foreach (row r2 in table_2)
  { 
     if(r.key1 == r2.key1 && r.key2 ==r2.key2 && r.soldQuantity > r2.Quantity)
     {
     updateRowInT1(); //r.Partner = r2.Partner;
     updateRowInT2(); //r2.Quantity = r2.Quantity - r.soldQuantity;
     break;
     }
  }
}
```

This part of code best describes what I need to do.
Is there any way to do this in SQL (with user-defined functions).
Because of changes in second table I can't use update and join. Or I can?

Also, this is part of ETL process done by Pentaho Kettle. Is perhaps way to do this inside this tool.?

Thanks

**Edit:**
I have changed code above.

**What I need to achieve?**

Regular Sales by Partner.

**What's wrong right now?**

When some SKU is sold in retail shop, I can see SKU LAST Partner. But, company I work for is buying same SKU from more Partners.
Slowly Changing Dimension is not applicable because when we switch partner on SKU, there is still some quantity of that SKU on shelf.

**Assumption:**

FIFO - first In first Out.

So, for initial matching, I need to compare (in date order) both sales and buying and to decrement bought quantity.

Comment: Just run two updates in a transaction.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Wouldn't it finish first table update first, than go to the second?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what conditions you are matching on?  Are you correlating data in table_1 and table_2 by some kind of key plus some other conditions?  Also when you update each table, are you trying to update table_2 with data from table_1 or is the update more like setting a literal value to a field?

Comment: @woot Hi, I have updated my question and code. Yes, I need to update both tables from each others values. Tough, a? :/

Answer (score 1):

You probably should be thinking in a more set oriented way.

Assuming I understand what you are trying to do properly, I would do this in two update statements:

```
-- Update table_1's Partner based on a row in table_2.
UPDATE table_1 r
SET    Partner = r2.Partner
FROM   table_2 r2
WHERE  r2.key1 = r.key1
AND    r2.key2 = r.key2;

-- Reduce the Quantity in table_2 based on table_1's soldQuantity  
UPDATE table_2 r2
SET    Quantity = r2.Quantity - r.soldQuantity
FROM   table_1 r
WHERE  r.key1 = r2.key1
AND    r.key2 = r2.key2
AND    r2.Quantity >= r.soldQuantity;

-- Both of these should be done in a transaction so it is all or none.  Commit the work.
COMMIT;
```

You can see the SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/cf920/8).